# How do I speed up /me/home requests?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, optimization, facebook-fql

I have an application where I want to show items that your friends have shared. This is basically a subset of data that would appear on your Facebook News Feed, so I am grabbing `/me/home` and then filtering out some things that I don't need.

The problem is that `/me/home` is extremely slow. I'm seeing a range of response times that is between 1200 and 10000 milliseconds with an average probably around 4 seconds.

Even with cached connections and a HTTP library that does SSL correctly these request times do not change much.

Does anyone know a better way to grab the News Feed? When I open Facebook in my browser, the News Feed appears pretty much immediately. So I am wondering if there is some Graph API call that is optimized for this data or has this result cached already.

Is there maybe an *FQL* alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in FQL. This query should get you started:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'others'
```

In the Graph API explorer on my feed, I get ~1000ms response times for the FQL query vs. ~2500ms for `me/home`.

For Facebook's home page, keep in mind that they use a series of AJAX queries to fill each of the boxes on your page a little at a time. I was on a very slow connection in a hotel last week and watched these fill box by box. The news feed fills first, five posts at a time, followed by the other boxes on the page. If page load performance could be an issue, you may want to move to an asynchronous model.

FQL will definitely help with that, as you'll be able to filter the data before it is returned by FB more finely than you can with just the Graph API.

Comment: This was a great suggestion. I am now actually sending a multi-FQL query with both a variation of this suggested query and a second one to resolve the actor_ids to real names. Works great and fast.